# R: ISO 8601 converting UTC to ISO 8601. An hour is added why?

Tags: r, datetime, time, utc, iso

So I'm looking to convert some ISO 8601 time to UTC format in R. For example:

```
library("lubridate")

x <- "2010-04-14-01-00-00-UTC"

datetime <- lubridate::ymd_hms(x)

datetime
[1] "2010-04-14 01:00:00 UTC"

strftime(datetime, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
[1] "2010-04-14T02:00:00Z"
```

However in ISO 8601 "Z" indicates UTC time and I would therefore have expected "2010-04-14T01:00:00Z", but an hour has been added onto the datetime. Why? Am I miss-understanding something?

What is the correct way in R to convert between the two? And to convert backwards?

Comment: Perhaps daylight savings adjustment?

Comment: the `Z` in your strftimepattern is probably interpreted as a literal Z, the datetime interpreted as localtime, and formatted according to `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S`. You'll have to instruct the datetime object you want it's time in UTC instead of localtime

Comment: @JacobH. I was under the impression that UTC was independent of daylight savings time and that were it present we would write: 2010-04-14T02:00:00+01:00 where "2010-04-14T02:00:00" is the local time and "+01:00" indicates that we were 1hr ahead of the zero meridian.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> `strftime(x, format = "", tz = "", usetz = FALSE, ...)`
>
> [...]
>
> `tz`  A character string specifying the time zone to be used for the
>   conversion. System-specific (see as.POSIXlt), but "" is the current
>   time zone, and "GMT" is UTC. Invalid values are most commonly treated
>   as UTC, on some platforms with a warning.

So, you need to specify the correct timezone:

```
strftime(datetime, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", tz = "UTC")
#[1] "2010-04-14T01:00:00Z"
```

Otherwise it takes the timezone from your system's locale settings:

```
strftime(datetime, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", usetz = TRUE)
#[1] "2010-04-14T03:00:00 CEST"
```